# Connecting Raspberry to Apple Time Capsule

Tags: time-machine, unix, airport, file-sharing

How to connect a raspberry to Apple Time Capsule? It should be easy but I faced several time consuming issues, I'm posting the solution as Q&A in the hope this can be useful to someone.

So... how to connect your Raspberry to Apple Time Capsule?

Answer (score 2):

I successful connected a raspberry with installed

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50+ #970 Mon Feb 20 19:12:50 GMT 2017 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

To Apple Time Capsule.

We need to speak with CIFS, that is a dialect of SMB, so you have be sure that

```
samba                            SMB/CIFS file, print, and login server for Unix
samba-common                     common files used by both the Samba server and client
samba-common-bin                 Samba common files used by both the server and the client
samba-dsdb-modules               Samba Directory Services Database
samba-libs:armhf                 Samba core libraries
samba-vfs-modules                Samba Virtual FileSystem plugins
```

are installed on Raspberry. Use this command to install any missing:

```
sudo apt-get install samba samba-common samba-common-bin samba-dsdb-modules  samba-vfs-modules samba-libs:armhf
```

Open Utility AirPort and find the IP Addresses of the Time Capsule, in my case I see 10.0.1.1 and 192.168.1.4, I suppose that you connected the raspberry to the Time Capsule device, so the address your Raspberry sees is the IP LAN, in my case is 10.0.1.1.

[image]

Now let's check which share are exposed and we can connect to. Issue this command and remember to replace 10.0.1.1 with your IP Address and "bigfoot" with the username for your Time Capsule

```
smbclient -U bigfoot -L 10.0.1.1 
Enter bigfoot's password:
```

When did it, I got this error:

```
Server does not support EXTENDED_SECURITY  but 'client use spnego = yes and 'client ntlmv2 auth = yes'
```

session setup failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

You can solve this problem changing the file /etc/samba/smb.conf, you have to add

```
client use spnego = no
```

into the [global] section in top of the /etc/samba/smb.conf file.
Try again the command smbclient to list the shares:

```
smbclient -U bigfoot -L 10.0.1.1 
Enter bigfoot's password: 

Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Apple Base Station] Server=[CIFS 4.32]

    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    IPC$            IPC       
    TimeCapsuleHD   Disk      
    750             Disk  

Domain=[WORKGROUP] OS=[Apple Base Station] Server=[CIFS 4.32]

    Server               Comment
    ---------            -------

    Workgroup            Master
    ---------            -------
```

Bingo! Here are the shared exposed, in my case I want to connect to the external drive connected to the Time Capsule's USB port, so my share name is 750.

The command from Raspberry will be:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/AppleTimeCapsule 
sudo  mount -t cifs  //10.0.1.1/750 /mnt/AppleTimeCapsule -o username=bigfoot,password=addhereyoursecretpassword,rw,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm
```